# CSS Fonts not working - Font icons displaying as codes

Tags: html, css, fonts

This is my website:
http://sonic3remastered.com/

If you look at the follow section at the bottom, you will see some codes such as `/f0d4`, `/f081` etc.

These are supposed to be CSS font icons, but they are displaying as codes instead of icons.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="ui-social-media color">
  <li class="twitter">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/sonic3onmobile"><span>Twitter</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="facebook">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sonic3onmobile"><span>Facebook</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="google-plus">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/103304727452387042300" rel="publisher"><span>Google Plus</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-social-media li a:before {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: inherit
}

.ui-social-media li a:hover {
    color: #5b5b5b
}

.ui-social-media li a span {
    display: none
}

.ui-social-media .facebook a:before {
    font-family: 'ui-glyphs';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    content: "/f0d4"
}

.ui-social-media .twitter a:before {
    font-family: 'ui-glyphs';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    content: "/f081"
}

.ui-social-media .google-plus a:before {
    font-family: 'ui-glyphs';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    content: "/f0d4"
}
```

How can I fix this?

I have opened Chrome developer tools and gone to Network > Fonts. The font seems to be loading, so I am not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using forward-slash `/`, when you need to be using backslash `\`.

Change that, and it'll fix it.

**Example**

```
.ui-social-media .google-plus a:before {
    font-family: 'ui-glyphs';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    content: "\f0d4" /* Not "/f0d4" */
}
```